# How to square exponential form?

Tags: complex-numbers

How to square this exponential form. Please help me?

$$ z = 5e^{i36.97^\circ}$$

$$ z^2 = ? $$

Comment: rule for exponentials: $(a^b)^c = a^{bc}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Square the modulus, double the argument.

$z^2 = 25e^{i73.94^{\circ}}$